# math proofs: use the definition of the limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta

I am asked to use the definition of the limit of a sequence to prove:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n-1}{2n+5}=\frac32.$$
My hint: this is only requires creative choosing of $N$ and applying the definition.  So thus far,I have:
$n\ge N \implies \left|\frac{3n-1}{2n+5}.\frac32\right|< \epsilon$.

Anyway,  I figured out I need solve for little $n$.  However each time I do that, I end up with a negative value of $-\frac{17}{4}\epsilon-\frac52$ and then I just get stuck and don't know what to do.  Could anyone please be of help?  Thanks.

Comment: It cut off the remainder of my question?  Anyway I keep finding n>(-17/4epsilon)-(5/2).  Is this poor algebra?  Bad understanding of the question?  I'm pretty lost on what I'm supposed to do from here I guess.  Any little bit of help would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: The sequence of characters `<e` seems to not display everything that comes after it.

Comment: Indeed, < signifies an opening html tag

Comment: Sorry it's all there.  I just had to go back a page.  It's there.  But Hagen... could you elaborate a little more with your hint, please?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing everything fine, except you're dropping the absolute values:

Since $\;\displaystyle\left|\frac{3n-1}{2n+5}-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|\frac{-17}{2(2n+5)}\right|=\frac{17}{2(2n+5)}$, you just have to solve $\displaystyle\frac{17}{2(2n+5)}<\epsilon$

to find a value of $N$ that will work.

---

You could also use $\displaystyle\frac{17}{2(2n+5)}<\frac{20}{2(2n+5)}=\frac{10}{2n+5}<\frac{10}{2n}=\frac{5}{n}$

and then solve $\displaystyle\frac{5}{n}<\epsilon$ to find a simpler expression for $N$,$\;\;$if you wanted to.

Comment: Oh...man do I ever feel stupid.  Well my pre-calc teacher would be really upset with me haha.  Common denominators... OF COURSE!!! No wonder this looked so messed up.  Ok.  So now after that... let me keep going and see what I discover here...

Comment: So the alternative you showed is a way to avoid the trouble of having 17 up in the numerator and satisfy the inequality right?  Assuming I go with that (which I'd rather as it makes finding n a lot easier), that makes n>5/epsilon.  Now I'm not quite sure what to do.  For now I'm just trying to get my head around what I need to do/understand mathematically before I write up the formal proof of this thing.

Comment: Yes, you're right, so now you can start something like this:  Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, and choose $N>\frac{5}{\epsilon}$.  If $n\ge N$, then $n>\frac{5}{\epsilon}$ so $|\frac{3n-1}{2n+5}-\frac{3}{2}|=|\frac{-17}{2(2n+5)}|=\frac{17}{2(2n+5)}$,  and then show that this is less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: Ok.  So let me see if I understand this now:  it looks like ideally, epsilon is really really close to zero, but is barely "above" it.  Assuming that n is greater than 5/epsilon, which in turn can be greater than or equal to big N, this makes a big big number (since we are taking 5 divided by a really small number barely above 0).  Plugging that whole idea into the 17/(2(2n+5)) we found earlier, that will make 17/(2(2n+5)) go the other way to a really small number.  So because that happens, are we are able to say by definition that our original limit is 3/2?

Comment: That's the right idea: we are showing that for any small positive number $\epsilon$, we can find a $N$ such that whenever $n\ge N$, then $|\frac{3n-1}{2n+5}-\frac{3}{2}|<\epsilon$.  As you say, as $\epsilon$ gets smaller, $N$ has to be chosen larger.  (Intuitively, we're showing that we can make the terms of the sequence as close to $\frac{3}{2}$ as we want by choosing n sufficiently large.)

Comment: Man thank you so much!! You rule.  About to take a break for the day then come back in the morning and knock this problem out.  I'll definitely be back on here if I run into anymore questions with this or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $\frac{3n-1}{2n+5}=\frac{\left(3n+\frac{15}2\right)-\frac{17}2}{2n+5}$

Comment: Do you mean n=3/2?

Comment: @billyredface88 $n$ is a variable tending to $\infty$.

Comment: I'm still stuck.  What does this say about big N?

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively as $n\to\infty$, the terms $an$ and $cn$ will be dominant in the expression $\frac{an+b}{cn+d}$ since they are increasing linearly whereas the terms $b$ and $d$ are constant. We should expect $\frac{an+b}{cn+d}\sim\frac{an}{cn}=\frac{a}{c}$.

This means the numerator should be "about" the denominator times $\frac{a}{c}$. In fact:

$$an+b=\frac{a}{c}(cn+d)+\square \tag{$\circ$}$$

for some constant $\square$. So we have

$$\frac{an+b}{cn+d}-\frac{a}{c}=\frac{\frac{a}{c}(cn+d)+\square}{cn+d}-\frac{a}{c}=\frac{\square}{cn+d}.$$

Given an $\varepsilon>0$, how big does $n$ have to be to guarantee $|\frac{\square}{cn+d}|<\varepsilon$?

(Note you can solve for $\square$ explicitly in $(\circ)$. Use your numbers for $a,b,c,d$ if you wish.)

Comment: So n>=N, abs((3n-1)/(2n+5)-3/2)<epsilon. We solve out and and find n>(-17/4epsilon)-(5/2).  Does this mean I need a value for N at least greater than or equal to this little n for the limit to be true?  I'm pretty lost now.